# Middle click on touchpad no longer works

Tags: touchpad, mouse

The touchpad on my laptop is the kind without separate buttons, but distinguishes **left clicks** (by clicking bottom left corner) from **right clicks** (by clicking bottom right corner). The problem is, **middle clicks** also used to work when I clicked the middle bottom part of the touchpad, but it no longer works after I've tried [this solution to a shaky cursor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/shaky-mouse-pointer-when-using-touchpad/8422#8422).

It fixed my shaky cursor problem, but now I can't use the middle click anymore; is there some way to bring back my middle click?

PS. Also, is there some way to change the scroll sensitivity manually? After the shaky cursor fix, my scrolls have lost the "flowy" feel to it unless I scroll fast.