# Update libinput driver

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

since eOS is based on Ubuntu 16.04, how can I update the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` to a newer version? I want to install [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) and there is a small problem for my touchpad using the current driver. In a newer version of the driver the problem is solved. Thanks.
I have to mention that I don't have any problems with my touchpad, I just want to update my libinput drver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shaky mouse pointer when using touchpad](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/shaky-mouse-pointer-when-using-touchpad)

Comment: When I install libinput my mouse, trackpad and keyboards stop working. Not sure why yet, just thought I'd post this here as a caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to upgrade libinput to fix some touchpad issues on my laptop, I detailed the process in another answer: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10213/8179