# Add latest libinput to Elementary

Tags: updates, touchpad

elementary is all about ease of use and aesthetics. As a mac user, I'm incredibly delighted to have finally stumbled upon such linux distro.
A huge turn-off at the beginning was the horrible pointer movement through touchpads, though. Something so simple and crucial to the user, which is often overlooked. It's not just that the sensitivity is way too high by default, also the acceleration is generally broken and gesture recognition unreliable.

After some research I could fix all these issues by simply updating libinput to the latest version 1.6. Elementary still has 1.2.x in its repos, which was incredibly improved over time.

So why not simply including a more recent libinput by default in loki? It's simple, it would be amazing for many new users and I don't see any drawbacks.

Thanks,
Moritz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loki is based on Ubuntu 16.04. It's dependent upon that for its software release versions.

This is also a possible repeat of this thread:
[Update libinput driver](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/update-libinput-driver)

Comment: thanks your response and the helpful link, I marked it as answered. Sorry for asking something that had been asked before! Nonetheless, I understand elementary is build upon 16.04, but again, why not bundling it with the latest libinput? It's not that elementary _is_ Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I completely agree