# Mouse pointer bounces around when using touchpad

Tags: mouse, dell

Hello I just installed elementay OS and I am running into a problem when using touchpad. My mouse point is shaky when I am using touchpad. My laptop is Dell Inspiron 3000.

This does not work: 
[Shaky mouse pointer when using touchpad](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/shaky-mouse-pointer-when-using-touchpad)

Comment: This may be a long shot but here are two things to try. First, make sure the touchpad is clean. Any residue on the surface can cause this...I've had it happen. Second, adjust the pointer speed in System settings as this may help. Report back with your progress if you could. Good Luck!

Comment: @linux_tim The touchpad works fine in Windows 10 and it is clean. I have adjusted the pointer speed to minimum but it still happens. When I tried 'sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics' it says 'The following packages have unmet dependencies' ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to the app called "System Settings", then go to the option "Displays" at the hardware section.
If you see a display called "Unknown Display" you can try to disable it and then click on the button Apply. 
Maybe this can solve your problem.

Comment: My display is 'Built In Display' and it can't be disabled